# How to write a text file with specific positions with FileStream?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to write a text file with this structure

[image]

For this I am working with Seek() and Write(), but every time I want to add a new data it is overwritten, and in the end only one line is written to the file

[image]

This is the code I am using

```cs
private async void CreacionArchivoBCD(ArchivoPerfil contenidoPerfil, string nombreFinalBCD, bool checkPrevia)
{
    var result = await ensayoDataProvider.ObtenerUexCapturador(checkPrevia, contenidoPerfil, codensSeleccionado.Id);
    var cant = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(result.Count()));


    ////TextWriter archivoExportar = new StreamWriter(nombreFinalBCD);
    ////archivoExportar.Close();

    var file = new FileStream(nombreFinalBCD, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    file.Seek(1, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    file.Write(cant, 0, cant.Length);
    byte[] newline = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);
    file.Write(newline, 0, newline.Length);

    int nroMedAux = 0;
    long rutaAux = 0;
    var cont = 0;
    var bandera = 0;
    //var posicion = 0;
    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        var primerByte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("00");
        file.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        file.Write(primerByte, 0, primerByte.Length);

        if (bandera == 0)
        {
            nroMedAux = item.IdMed;
            rutaAux = item.Ruta;
            bandera = 1;
        }

        var tipo = item.GetType();

        if (nroMedAux != item.IdMed || rutaAux != item.Ruta)
        {
            nroMedAux = item.IdMed;
            rutaAux = item.Ruta;
            file.Write(newline, 0, newline.Length);
        }

        foreach (var pi in tipo.GetProperties())
        {
            var propName = pi.Name;
            var propValue = pi.GetValue(item, null)?.ToString();
            var propValueAux = propName == "Campo" ? item.GetType().GetProperty("Valor").GetValue(item, null) : propValue;

            if (propName == "IdMed" || propName == "Valor")
            {
                continue;
            }

            //TODO: buscar posicion y ancho por nombre campo
            var posicion = BuscarPosicion(propName, propValue, contenidoPerfil);
            //var ancho = BuscarAncho(propName, contenidoPerfil);

            Debug.WriteLine(propName);
            Debug.WriteLine(propValueAux);
            Debug.WriteLine(posicion);

            if (posicion == -1)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var lacadena = propValue;
            var lacadenAux = propName == "Campo" ? propValueAux : propValue;
            var cadena = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(lacadenAux.ToString());
            file.Seek(posicion, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            file.Write(cadena, 0, cadena.Length);
        }
    }

    file.Close();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how you should do it. Since you are writing text to a file, you should use a `StreamWriter`.
Then to create the column formatting, simply use `string.PadLeft` (or `string.PadRight`).
To handle streams (or `IDisposable` implementations in general) use the `using` statement. Don't close resources explicitly.
Also use the async API to improve the performance.

The following example shows the pattern you should use:

1. Generate the data structure (rows)
2. Format the data
3. Write all data at once to the file

The algorithm takes different cell value lengths into account to generate even columns.

If you use .NET Standard 2.1 (.NET Core 3.0, .NET 5) you can even make use of `IAsyncDisposable`.

```cs
private async Task WriteDataTableToFileAsync(string filePath)
{
  List<List<string>> rows = GenerateData();
  string fileContent = FormatData("4080", rows, 4);
  await WriteToFileAsync(fileContent, filePath);
}

private List<List<string>> GenerateData()
{
  // Generate the complete data first
  var rows = new List<List<string>>
  {
    // Row 1
    new List<string>
    {
      // Cells
      "00",
      "1",
      "LD126",
      "NN",
      "1",
      "0",
      "0 0",
      "49",
      "2"
    },
    // Row 2
    new List<string>
    {
      // Cells
      "00",
      "1",
      "Rell",
      "NN",
      "1",
      "0",
      "0 0",
      "49",
      "2"
    }
  };

  return rows;
}

private string FormatData(string preamble, List<List<string>> rows, int columnGapWidth)
{
  preamble = preamble.PadLeft(preamble.Length + 1) + Environment.NewLine;
  var fileContentBuilder = new StringBuilder(preamble);
  var columnWidths = new Dictionary<int, int>();
  int columnCount = rows.First().Count;

  foreach (List<string> cells in rows)
  {
    var rowBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnCount; columnIndex++)
    {
      if (!columnWidths.TryGetValue(columnIndex, out int columnWidth))
      {
        int maxCellWidthOfColumn = rows
          .Select(cells => cells[columnIndex])
          .Max(cell => cell.Length);
        columnWidth = maxCellWidthOfColumn + columnGapWidth;
        columnWidths.Add(columnIndex, columnWidth);
      }

      string cell = cells[columnIndex];
      rowBuilder.Append(cell.PadRight(columnWidth));
    }
     
    fileContentBuilder.Append(rowBuilder.ToString().TrimEnd());
    fileContentBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
  }

  string fileContent = fileContentBuilder.ToString().TrimEnd();
  return fileContent;
}

private async Task WriteToFileAsync(string fileContent, string filePath)
{
  await using var destinationFileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
  await using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(destinationFileStream);
  await streamWriter.WriteAsync(fileContent);
}
```

You can further improve the implementation: add a `Data`, `Row` and a `Cell` class. The `Row` class has a `Cell` collection. The `Data` class has a `Row` collection and additional data like the preamble or formatting info like the column gap width. This way you eliminate method parameters to improve readability. Then replace the current `List<List<string>>` data structure with the `Data` class.

Comment: me olvidé de decir que el archivo de arriba se llena con el resultado de una query

Comment: no hablo espanol.

Comment: I forgot to say that the file is filling with the result of a query, therefore the result is dynamic

Comment: @LaraYs I know. I know. This is example data. You must modify your real code to produce a nested list of rows and cells like in the example. The use the FormatData and WriteToFileAsync to write the data as table to a file. Your job is to implement the GenerateData() method and return a List<List<string>> of all data. It should be clear that the data used in my example is not real and just serves the purpose of illustration. It is just showing you how to create the proper data structure (nested list). The rest (data formatting and file output)  is working and can be directly used.

Comment: @LaraYs I don't speak Spanish. Because your code is not using English, only Spanish people can read it. When you write code in English, your code can be read internationally. WPF and .NET is English too. ... To make the example work, take the FormatData() and WriteToFileAsync() as they are. Only rewrite GenerateData to return real data.

Comment: @LaraYs The important point is that te way you are writing to a file is not good in many aspects. The input, the data that is written, doesn't matter. To keep example short, I used fake data. You can cop&paste the complete example and run it. Then rewrite the GenerateData() method and let it return real data. That's all you have to do. The rest will continue to work.

Comment: Finally your code worked for me, I had to modify some words to match my code, but print what is important, I can not handle the PadRight and PadLeft well but that is a detail, Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 0):

Before `file.Close()`, add `file.Flush()` or `await file.FlushAsync()` -> this flushes the buffer to the output.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.flush?view=net-6.0.

Comment: file.flush dentro del "For" o solo antes del file.close?

Comment: You can call Flush many times, so you can put it inside the for loop if you want. You cannot call it after close(). I updated my answer to include a useful link.

Comment: Flush() is called automatically when Close() is called.